# how to organize <li> and <ul> to show on treeView in c#

Tags: c#, treeview, html-agility-pack

I have this html code :

```html
<div id="categories">
<ul>
<li id="catn4LsQd93KqA" position="0" ><a href="#" class="">news</a><ul>
                <li id="cat2JgdgXE_pc" position="0" ><a href="#" class="">news1</a></li>
                 <li id="cat2JkdsXE" position="1" ><a href="#" class="">news2</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li id="catIrTZ3KxgBdQ" position="1" ><a href="#" class="">movie</a><ul>
  <li id="cat2JkSIiXE_dc" position="0" ><a href="#" class="">movie1</a></li>
  <li id="catYDEJxdLpWtQ" position="1" ><a href="#" class="">movie2</a></li>
  <li id="catsUaLR6HD-bY" position="2" ><a href="#" class="">movie3</a></li>
 </ul></li></ul></div>
```

These code change from server and add new catagoris (li) or (ul)

I mant to show this codes in C# treeView using htmlagilitypack or any thing else is there any way ?

Comment: Hey why don't you use Javascript/HTML components for creating trees? look at this for example http://gijgo.com/tree/demos/bootstrap-treeview

Answer (score 0):

You need to create treeview from html list code?

Try something like this

rootNode is categories

```
void LoadTree(TreeNode treeNode, HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode rootNode)
        {
            foreach (var node in rootNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                TreeNode n = new TreeNode(node.InnerText);
                node.Attributes.Select(a => a.Name + "=" + a.Value)
                               .ToList()
                               .ForEach(x => n.Nodes.Add(x));
                treeNode.Nodes.Add(n);

                LoadTree(n, node);
            }
        }
```